# Remove an unwanted space between the author and comma using APACITE

Tags: citing, apa-style

I recently started using the APACITE package but when I put a citation in the text I get an unwanted space between the author and the comma, before the year (i.e. Author-Space-Comma-Space-Year). I have been using `\shortcite`.

I have attached a photo as an example.

[image]

I'm not sure why this space is appearing. Does anyone have advice on how to remove it?

Associated code:

```
\documentclass{../bits/thesis}
\usepackage{../bits/apacite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%   \usepackage{amssymb}
%   \usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{setspace} 
%   \usepackage{sidecap}
%   Verbatim allows commenting of sections
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{acronym}

\newcommand{\etal}{{\it et al.}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\defaultspacing}{\singlespacing}    % will be overridden in skeleton.tex
\newcommand{\um}{$\mu$m}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.65in}
\begin{document}

[...]
in the retina and neural structures of the eye \shortcite{Fairhall2006}, as well as
[...]

\bibliographystyle{../bits/jovcite}
\bibliography{../bits/library}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added a section of the code in the OP. I there are other little bits and pieces but I am confident that they are not problematic. I used APACITE from "https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite"

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that this behaviour doesn't occur when there are two authors in the reference, only when there is one.

Comment: Why do you have some of the files required in an extra folder `bits`? Make it a lot more complicated.

Comment: Because this is a big document, and I have designed it so that I can compile individual chapters, or the whole thesis as separate documents. So to keep the structure neat, I keep essential files in 'bits', and then each chapter goes into different folders. Is that not good latex practice? Thanks.

Comment: is is extra work for you to remember and follow your structure, it will be extra work for us to follow your structure (or revert it to the standard). We cannot be sure if your file `apacite.sty` is modified (cannot know that in any case). by the way, we don't have the class (there are hundreds out there called `thesis.cls`) and the sample bib-entry.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the comments, and the help. I realise that I have been a little cryptic, largely due to my lack of understanding in my own latex preamble. I think I have resolved the problem now, and it may have been due to formatting in the final bibliography. I'll update if it's deemed necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time. I sorted the problem by cleaning up my installation of apacite, and restating all of the bibliography declarations and inclusions. All works now, not sure what was causing the original problem though.